# HTML 5 <a> download attribute not working on Firefox Mozilla?

Tags: css, html, mozilla

Hi all I just want to allow user to download image on click of button .
I have used  tag in my project and its download attribute which is provided in html5. My following code working fine on Chrome but in Firefox Mozilla when I click on button it just redirecting me on the specified path.
Please tell me what is going wrong .

```
 <div style="display:inline-block; position:relative; ">
      <img src="https://stemvideodev.s3.amazonaws.com/6b72051541e948cb8ace2d83d3895901-THUMBNAIL-1.jpg" title="" alt="">
         <a href="https://stemvideodev.s3.amazonaws.com/6b72051541e948cb8ace2d83d3895901-THUMBNAIL-1.jpg" download="image.png">
            <input type="button" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0; " value="Download">
        </a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe avoid to wrap an input with a link...

Answer (score 5):

According to the HTML5 definition of the [`a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), it must not contain “interactive descendants”, and `input` elements are by definition interactive. The markup is thus invalid. All bets are off. The nesting rules are set to avoid complications in event handling.

So if you want to have the `download` attribute *and* some button appearance, you need to use just an `a` element and style it to look like a button. Here’s a sketch, to be tuned according to your preferences for button style:

```css
.dbutton {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  color: #000;
  background: #ddd;
  border: #333 outset 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.1em 0.2em;
  font: 90% sans-serif;
}
```

```html
 <div style="display:inline-block; position:relative; ">
      <img src="https://stemvideodev.s3.amazonaws.com/6b72051541e948cb8ace2d83d3895901-THUMBNAIL-1.jpg" title="" alt="">
         <a href="https://stemvideodev.s3.amazonaws.com/6b72051541e948cb8ace2d83d3895901-THUMBNAIL-1.jpg" download="image.png"
         class="dbutton">Download</a>
</div>
```

Comment: nice answer this is working for me ,but there is again one problem this solution. This working when i give static value to the src and href attribute of <img> and <a> tag respectively but in my  project the value comes for these attribute dynamically then again it is giving same result i.e opening  image in browser on click of  download. .

Comment: @KuldeepMore, I think you need to post specific code (sample of generated HTML and CSS that actually reproduces the issue), probably as a new question.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. I daresay, an accepted-answer deserving scholar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="text-wrap"><img src="your img.jpg" alt="">
<a href="download.jpg" class="myButton" download="img name" title="Download">
    <img src="/path/to/image" alt="Download">
</a></div>
```

Can you please try like this..

Comment: I can't bcoz I am generating this div dynamically through javascript.If u have any other solution plz replay.

Comment: @KuldeepMore, are you saying that you cannot change the markup? What kind of an answer are you expecting then?

Comment: @Jukka , I want to say that the above code which I have mentioned in my question working fine in Chrome means it is downloaded image on button click , but when I test this code on Firefox Mozilla it is just displaying image.